# Advantage of Ir-based vs Alq3 OLED material, is quantum yield more important over the cost?

Tags: organometallic-compounds, semiconductors

This Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED#Material_technologies mentions a couple of molecules that are used for OLED.

The Ir-based compound has [~ 100% quantum efficiency](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1409582), while Alq3 [may ~30% quantum efficiency](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0009261495014241)

But iridium is way more expensive than aluminum ([2,550 USD per troy ounce  ~ 82.00 USD per gram](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1046369/iridium-price/) vs [2,846 USD per ton](https://markets.businessinsider.com/commodities/aluminum-price) ). (Using cost of metal just a rough measure, e.g., [The core compounds at the heart of OLED displays are often made with expensive substances such as iridium, a rare metal that sells for nearly $19 per gram.](https://cen.acs.org/articles/94/i28/rise-OLED-displays.html), certainly complete comparison is more meaningful)

Higher quantum efficiency is an advantage. But, does it worth the price difference? Could lower quantum efficiency of Alq3 be compensated by higher energy consumption? Or Ir-based system is in exploration phase, so to speak.

And actually which one or something else is used in the OLED monitor currently in phone/monitor/TV?

Comment: Please don't abbreviate Wikipedia as wiki. I personally think this question is too broad and cannot be answered within the scope of this site.

Comment: Thanks. Edited. Any suggestions about how to narrow it down? My main question is about Ir vs Al. Sorry that I am not familiar with this site.

Comment: @Fancourt3000 To ease comparison between the price per unit of weight, I recommend you use units within the same system, e.g., the price per gram for the more expensive ([an example](https://www.strem.com/catalog/v/77-0425/31/iridium_870987-63-6)), and the price per (metric S.I.) ton for the more affordable.  It is *not wrong* if you want to express the price in other units more familiar to you *in addition*, like temperatures in degree Celsius, in degree Fahrenheit, or in Kelvin. (Even in countries were S.I. units dominate daily life, there are occasions where (troy) ounces remain used.)

Comment: I tried to add a paragraph explain my confusing point and narrow the scope of the question, say Alq3 is lower quantum efficiency, but low cost. Could the monitor uses more electricity to make it work as iridium based system? Electricity is a cost, price of metal is also a cost. Please let me know what is needed to reopen the question. Thank you!

Comment: Using absolute metal costs is very misleading. What has to be compared is difference of production monitor cost versus difference of lifetime spent energy cost.

Comment: The metal cost is somehow a rough measure, I think, e.g., in https://cen.acs.org/articles/94/i28/rise-OLED-displays.html, 'The core compounds at the heart of OLED displays are often made with expensive substances such as iridium, a rare metal that sells for nearly $19 per gram.'

Comment: What is the cost of metallic iridium in a single OLED device, compared to the device cost ?

Comment: great question, need to look for it